# Appending print-statement-like information to a list

Tags: python, list, append

I'm making a sort of history generation program in python heavily inspired by Dwarf Fortress. In the program, I want a list of events, in that list being smaller lists such as 'death_events' and 'war_events' etc.

The problem I am having is that I would like to be able to look through these lists to see events in the world, and I don't know what way to save that sort of information to a list. e.g:

```
events = []
learning_events = []

print('The', i.race, i.name, 'has learned about', i.knowledge, 'from the god of', god_teacher.sphere + ',', god_teacher.name)

learning_events.append('In the year', world_age, 'the', i.race, i.name, 'learned about', i.knowledge, 'from the god', god_teacher.name, 'a god of', god_teacher.sphere)
events[0] = learning_events
```

I thought I would somehow be able to save that to a list, but I get:

```
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (11 given)
```

I'm not sure if using a variable to put this information into a list as this "event" could happen many times with different information each time.

Comment: It seems like you want to combine all those pieces into one string and add that string to `learning_events`. See [`.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have heard of using that before but didn't know why it was useful or even necessary

Comment: You should consider swapping from a `list` of `list` of `str` to a `dict` of `list` of `str` like so: `events = {'learning': ["X learned Y", "Z unlerned W"], "deaths": ["Z drowned", "X was burnt to death"]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the dict otherwise you'll have multiple learning lists in the event list.

The best way to write the string would be to use `.format()` on the string:

```
# do this once, so you don't overwrite previous events
events = {}
events['learning'] = []

learn_skill_utterance = "The {i.race} {i.name} has learned about {i.knowledge} from the god of {god_teacher.sphere}".format(i=dwarf, god_teacher=god)

# add string to list of events
events['learning'].insert(0, learn_skill_utterance)
```

This way an object will fill the parameters in the string. This can allow you to write these utterances much quicker.

Here is a little OOP example:

```
In [1]: class Dwarf:
   ...:     def __init__(self, name, size):
   ...:         self.name = name
   ...:         self.size = size
   ...:

In [2]: happy = Dwarf('Happy', 8)

In [3]: happy.size
Out[3]: 8

In [4]: "{dwarf.name} is size: {dwarf.size}".format(dwarf=happy)
Out[4]: 'Happy is size: 8'
```

I wouldn't make `knowledge` that is being learnt, as a dwarf attribute.

---

#### Side note:

If you append strings to the list containing `{dwarf.name}` without applying `.format()` on them, you can always apply `.format(dwarf=happy)` later when you need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of combining different `str`s into a single one, as you want to do. `print()` by default combines all its arguments into a `str` but this is not the case for most of the functions.

The most pythonic way to join `str`s is [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
"This is my sentence with {} placeholders that I can replace by whatever I like".format("bracket")
```

Basically it replaces {} with the first argument. You can use names for the variables:

```
"This is {first} sentence with {second} placeholders".format(first="another", second="bracket")
```

Or you can change the order:

```
"This is {1} sentence with {0} placeholders".format("bracket", "another")
```

There are multiple more formatting options such as choosing the amount of decimals for floats and so on.

In your case you could use:

```
learning_events.append("In the year {} the {} {} learned about {} from the god {}, a god of {}.".format(world_age, i.race, i.name, i.knowledge, god_teacher.name, god_teacher.sphere))
```